# Run all TestCases with PyUnit

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I remember in JUnit there is a way to run EVERY TestCase you have created or only those in a selected file.

Is there a way to accomplish this in PyUnit?

I can easily run the tests that are in my currently open file, but I'd like the option of running ALL tests (spread out across different files).

I've seen the TestSuite, but my understanding is that that requires manually adding a TestCase  to the TestSuite everytime you create a new TestCase. I was hoping to accomplish this automatically.

For instance, I have the following TestCases (each with several `test<Method Name>` methods):

```
class TestFamily(unittest.TestCase)
class TestFamilyMember(unittest.TestCase)
```

How can I run all the tests in `TestFamily` AND `TestFamilyMember`?

**Alternative**

Check out [nosetests](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running unittest in [test discovery mode](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html?highlight=unittest#test-discovery)?

While in your project directory, type `python -m unittest discover`.  This will run all tests that are in files directly importable in the current directory.

From the PyUnit/unittest documentation, for this to work:

> In order to be compatible with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages importable from the top-level directory of the project

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have all your tests in one folder, right-click on the folder and got to `Run As`.

There should be an option there for pyunit tests (name may vary depending on your configuration, mine shows Python unit-test. You can change configurations from the next option (`Run As` , `Run Configurations`).

EDIT: Also, check the unittest documentation http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/unittest.html?highlight=unittest#unittest . IIRC, you can append a testsuite to another testsuite (same way as appending tests to a suite).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to run all your test cases using TestLoader in PyUnit

Note : Make sure all your test methods starts with the annotations test

Hope this blog helps you !

http://scriptforandroid.blogspot.in/2017/04/python-unittest-pyunit.html?m=1